# show diff for a file between several commits, to see how the file evolved

Tags: git

I know how to display the last commits where a file was present:

```
git log -30 -- js/functions.js
```

but now I would like to see how the file evolved. I would like to display the `diff` between each of these commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git log -p` to show diff with your log.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Example:

```
git log --stat
```

You have more on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I also like `gitk`, which is often bundled with some git installations (`brew`, `git bash` for Windows, etc.)

`gitk js/functions.js`

Will do what you are looking for and more. `gitk` will even tell you to which branches a commit belongs to.